# How to create the code signing certificate through the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 4.0

`makecert` tool has the `-eku` option for describing the enhanced key usage object identifiers (OIDs) into the certificate. It allows to make the certificates for *code signing* and for other purposes. But it is not a cmdlet.

New PowerShell versions have the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet for local testing of the scripts. But it creates the certificate that can't be used for code signing:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.SomeSite.com -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

I don't see an option which is similar of `-eku`.

How can I set the destination of my new Self-Signed Certificate (created through `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet) for possibility of its use for code signing? Or is it possible to do the same via other cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `New-SelfSignedCertificate` on PS 4 is rather basic.

However [Powershell v5](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.640).aspx) has the parameters that you would require to create specific keys.

Specifically a `Keyusage` parameter that takes

```
-- CertSign
-- CRLSign
-- DataEncipherment
-- DecipherOnly
-- DigitalSiganture
-- EncipherOnly
-- KeyAgreement
-- KeyEncipherment
-- None (default) 
-- NonRepudiation
```

and a `KeyUsageProperty` taking

```
-- All
-- Decrypt
-- KeyAgreement
-- None (default) 
-- Sign
```

Are you specifically tied to v4? If you can upgrade to v5 you should be able to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this question as I was also looking for an answer to set Enhanced Key Usage (EKU) field for code signing using PowerShell `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command.

It can be done using the `-TextExtension` parameter to set EKU value. As an example, the following PowerShell (tested on PowerShell 5.1) script allows to create a 3-years self signed code signing certificate with extended key usage (and export it from the current user's certificates store to pfx file format):

```
# Enhanced Key Usage
$EKU = "2.5.29.37"
$EKU_CODE_SIGNING = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3"

$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=Testing Code Signing,E=info@mycompany.com,O=My Company" `
                          -FriendlyName "My Code Signing Certificate" `
                          -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(3) `
                          -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My `
                          -TextExtension @("$EKU={text}$EKU_CODE_SIGNING")

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -Force -AsPlainText

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($certificate.Thumbprint)" -FilePath "codesigning.pfx" -Password $password
```

**Note:** As a shortcut, the `-Type CodeSigningCert` parameter can be specified with the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command instead of explicitly adding the EKU_CODE_SIGNING string to the `-TextExtension` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PS' cert provider to access different cert stores (user vs machine), but that won't help with your OID problem. I suggest you look at .NET support for X509 certs. Google ".net x509 certificate" and you'll find the X509Certificate class on MSDN. From there read the class documentation and any overview documentation to see if creation of OIDs is supported. If .NET doesn't support it then you'd have to use P/Invoke to invoke native Windows CNG (cryptography next generation) APIs